# NVidia, Compiz and Desktop Effect Problem

Tags: opensuse, desktop, nvidia, compiz

I installed the Nvidia driver on OpenSuse 12.1.

The driver was downloaded from http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers.

But after I installed the Nvidia driver, I cannot activate any desktop effects ("The following desktop effects could not be activated".) The whole graphic rendering is not optimal or not good. For example, if Dolphin is opening, you can see a small Dolphin icon jump. But during the animation the icon leaves a grey trail. Also if the window is moved, it starts to jitter.

Here is my xorg.conf

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 7600 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 7600 GT"
    BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "Composite" "On"
EndSection
```

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind OpenSuse 12.1 is relatively new and this may well be a bug that will be ironed out in coming releases. I recommend you use the `zypper` to manage your driver download to make syre you get the right version for your card and make updates easier on yourself. Follow http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_drivers

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did the mistake. I followed the site what you posted. I just totally forgot about it. But this issue is also from previous version of OpenSuse. And not just on this Linux distribution. But I tried all the solutions what i could find. But maybe you are right. And i need just to wait. :-(